# Why do I get an 'internal error' when using CCXT to create market orders in Coinbase API with Python?

Tags: python, coinbase-api, ccxt

CCXT-coinbase create market order.
I am trying to create market order on coinbase with CCXT.

```
coinbase {"error":"INTERNAL","error_details":"internal error","message":"internal error"}
```

It is resulting in this error

```
params1: {'side': 'BUY', 'params': {}, 'amount': '0.01','symbol':'BTC-USDT'}
params2: {'side': 'BUY', 'params': {}, 'amount': '0.01','symbol':'BTC/USDT'}
```

I tried both parameters, but it still returns an internal server error.

I need any help on passing proper params to create market orders.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.